# Unable to connect to fedora server from windows using vncviewer Connection timed out(10060)

Tags: windows, fedora, vnc-viewer

i have one Linux server which is running fedora17. i have installed vnc server on this machine. and i am trying to connect to this server from windows through vncviewer. But i am getting following error message ::

Connection timed out(10060)

Please help me to solve this issue...

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the port you're using is open on your server (for example using [this website](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/)). Default port for VNC is 5900.

If it's not, check any firewalls and make sure the port is forwarded correctly.

If it's open, try adding :5900 to your server's address in viewer.

Comment: Now i am able to connect but blank screen is showing...